# Switching 3-phase power between two appliances using a 3-phase switch

Tags: wiring

In my garage I have an electrical 3-phase dryer.  I want to add a new 3-phase  air-conditioner. I want to be able to switch between the two of them, by using a 3-phase switch. This way, only one of these two appliances, can work at any given time.  In the market, such switches, for residential use are already available for purchase.

I was told by two electricians that I am not allowed to install the switch, because such installation is a violation of the building code. My questions are:

1. Is my proposed installation of a 3-phase switch a violation of the building code?
2. If the answer is a 'YES', then why is it so?
3. If I cannot use this switch, what are my legitimate options to make the dryer and the air conditioner able to only work one at a time?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the switch you want to use, or at least the make and model number?

Comment: Where in the world are you that your dryer and A/C are both three phase appliances?

Comment: Also, seems like an XY problem. Why do you need to have them not operate simultaneously?

Answer (score -2):

I really don't know why you couldn't. If the switch is made for residential use for that purpose I don't see why not. They said it was against the building code? Not the electrical code? I could not see why the carpenters would care what the electricians did (building code versus electrical code).

Comment: If you are going to vote my answer down, do you care to share any thought you passer by'ers? I am trying to get the conversation going. Please share your thoughts also.

Comment: We can't really answer the question until we know WTF sort of building code the OP labors under.

Comment: I voted down what seemed to be a spurious guess, rather than facts from the NEC or IRC code books.  The fact that a licensed electrician said it WASN'T permitted means you should cite a reference that ALLOWS it.